# htaccess rule to include two query strings

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I have a url:

```
www.example.com/?action=viewCategoryName&categoryName=Events&page_identifier=about
```

And would like to create a rule that would return the page if the following is entered:

```
'www.example.com/events/about'
```

Is it possible to write the rule to include the two query strings? I have come up with the below but its not working as expected.

```
RewriteRule ^$2/([a-z0-9,&-]+)/?$1 ?viewCategoryNameandArticle&categoryName=$2&page_identifier=$1 [L,NC,QSA,B]
```

Many Thanks!
Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /?action=viewCategoryName&categoryName=$1&page_identifier=$2 [L]
```

Comment: perfect! Will accept your answer in 9 minutes :) 

Many thanks Justin!!

Comment: Would you mind explaining how to include an ambersand/& in the regular expression?  I've tried ([^/]+)/([^/],&-+)$

Comment: Ampersand (`&`) is already accepted with my rule. Actually, the pattern `[^/]+` means `one or more characters except /`